# what is accuracy in terms of text line segmentation?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr, image-segmentation

What are the parameters for computing accuracy of text line after segmentation?
For text line segmentation, may I use same PNSR, FP, TP etc.?

Segmented image:
[image: Segmented image]

Is the accuracy 100% as all four lines are segmented? What is the accuracy of this image? So that I can compute for the whole dataset.

I also created groundtruth for my dataset, but I can't use it because the size of the groundtruth image and the segmented image is different.

Groudtruth image (size: 937 x 74):

[image: Groudtruth image]

Segmented image (size: 960 x 69):

[image: Segmented image 2]

Comment: There is no scientific way of evaluating accuracy of a segmentation, unless you know the ground truth, but that is what you are looking for

Comment: Is there any way of finding accuracy without ground truth?

Comment: If image-size prevents you from getting ground truth you can change it with imresize.
Conceptually, with no ground truth data one can use a proven model for the task and compare its valid results with those you got.

Comment: On above-given images I tested accuracy.But, what do these values mean? Is segmentation is accurate or not?
MSE:   44.56 
PSNR: 31.6752428  
[accuracy, sensitivity, specificity, precision, recall, f_measure, gmean] 
  0.5391,       NaN,       0.5391,         0,       NaN ,      NaN       NaN